# Selecionar radiobuttons de valores diferentes

Tags: html

Estou iniciando na área de html e estou fazendo umas páginas pra mim mesmo(para teste) e em uma que fiz tem alguns `radiobuttons`, a questão é que eu gostaria de deixa-los obrigatório a seleção de 2 deles, um em cada área, e que as cores selecionadas não fossem a mesma, tipo tem de ser diferente as cores. tipo, a cor da letra não pode ser a mesma que a cor do fundo. Digamos que o usuário selecione a cor preta, e se ele selecionar preta na cor de fundo também irá exibir uma msg:"As cores não podem ser iguais". no caso ele terá de selecionar cores diferentes para a letra e fundo.

```css
.bubble
 {
  border-radius: 10%;
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .10);
 } 
    
.bubble-sm
 {
  width: 20px!important;
  height: 20px!important; 
 }
```

```html
<br>COR DA LETRA<br><br>

<input type="radio" name="color" value="preto" required='true'><div class="bubble bubble-sm" style="background-color: #000000"></div>
<input type="radio" name="color" value="azul" required='true'><div class="bubble bubble-sm" style="background-color: #000080"></div>       

<br><br>COR DO FUNDO<br><br>
  
<input type="radio" name="color2" value="preto" required='true'><div class="bubble bubble-sm" style="background-color: #000000"></div>
<input type="radio" name="color2" value="azul" required='true'><div class="bubble bubble-sm" style="background-color: #000080"></div>
```

Comment: é bem provável que terá que usar uma condiçãoem alguma linguagem específica..

Comment: e como seria isso? js?

Comment: creio que sim....Tem alguma noção de js ?

Comment: muito pouco kkkm tentei mexer com function etc, mas n conseguir nada

Comment: > @Jefter Rocha
> > Eu aconselho a você dar uma lida nos seguinte frameworks:
> **Materialize** ou o mais conhecido o **Bootstrap**.
> > **Porque estou te falando isto?** >**R:** Frameworks te ajudam e facilitam na hora do desenvolvimento, como por exemplo utilizando sua dúvida
> acima, no Materialize você só precisa incluir um nome dentro da class
> e já está pronto seus botões e seus "efeitos" no Bootstrap é o mesmo.
> > Dê uma olhada no site do **Materialize** por exemplo: > http://materializecss.com/forms.html
> > Agora para fazer isto com **HTML5** e **CSS3** puro você irá precisar aprend

Comment: Caso alguma das respostas for correta, considere validá-la clicando no icon verde abaixo as setas de avaliação... Boa Sorte...

Comment: @ThiagoDeBonis Não faço ideia de como usar esse **Materialize** :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desconheço fazer isso apenas com `html`, então usei `javascript`.

Não está muito otimizado, mas já eu uma ideia...

```html
<body>
<br>COR DA LETRA<br><br>

<input id="black" type="radio" name="color" value="preto" required='true'><div class="bubble bubble-sm" style="background-color: #000000"></div>
<input id="blue" type="radio" name="color" value="azul" required='true'><div class="bubble bubble-sm" style="background-color: #000080"></div>       

<br><br>COR DO FUNDO<br><br>
  
<input id="f_black" type="radio" name="color2" value="preto" required='true'><div class="bubble bubble-sm" style="background-color: #000000"></div>
<input id="f_blue" type="radio" name="color2" value="azul" required='true'><div class="bubble bubble-sm" style="background-color: #000080"></div>
</body>
<style>
.bubble
 {
  border-radius: 10%;
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .10);
 } 
    
.bubble-sm
 {
  width: 20px!important;
  height: 20px!important; 
 }
</style>
<script>

  var blue = document.getElementById("blue");
  var black = document.getElementById("black");
  var f_blue = document.getElementById("f_blue");
  var f_black = document.getElementById("f_black");
  f_blue.addEventListener("click", function()
      {
       if(blue.checked == true){
       alert("Selecione outra cor");
       f_blue.checked = false;}
      });
   f_black.addEventListener("click", function()
      {
       if(black.checked == true){
       alert("Selecione outra cor");
       f_black.checked = false;}
      });
   blue.addEventListener("click", function()
      {
       if(f_blue.checked == true){
       alert("Selecione outra cor");
       f_blue.checked = false;}
      });
   black.addEventListener("click", function()
      {
       if(f_black.checked == true){
       alert("Selecione outra cor");
       f_black.checked = false;}
      });
</script>
```

Comment: isso é tipo o que eu quero mesmo, mas fui tentar aplicar mais algumas cores(outros 2 input) e não funcionou com eles...

Comment: É cada caso é um caso,  se o código de seu objetivo final, agente tenta adequar...

Comment: Não não! foi erro meu mesmo vlw! era isso que procurava!